# How lethal is Sombra's Machine Pistol?

Tags: overwatch

How much damage does it do up close, and what's the maximum range I can be at until the damage begins to drop off? How much does the damage drop off, and what's the max drop off?

Can the weapon be burst-fired to eliminate the high spread, or is the spread unmanageable at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[That's the most information](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Sombra) we have at the moment.

> Falloff range : 35 to 55 meters
>
> Damage : 2.4 - 8

So max damage, 8 times 60 for 480 damage at 35 meters. (**IF** you land all bullets even with the spray (and x2 for all headshots))

The spread maxes out after 3 or so bullets and last for more than a second after letting go of the fire button making tapping really hard.

Long range wise, there is not much to do with this weapon. 2.4 damage a bullet with a maximum of 3 bullets that are somewhat accurate is really not enough to do much.

Comment: 8 - non HS ? so 960 max damage ?

Comment: Well... Yeah... If you can land all bullets on headshots. If you do that in game, go buy yourself a lottery ticket asap.